# JTree representing a graph

Tags: java, swing, tree, jtree, defaultmutabletreenode

I am using the JTree Swing utility to represent a Tree that actually have loops. I have a single node called root, but some of the children will eventually point back to other parts of the tree, thus not making it a true tree, but rather a graph.

My Java application keeps locking up, (no exceptions being thrown, no stack overflow... etc) when I try to use the little gray arrows to expand and contract parts of the graph.

My question is, does JTree require that none of the DefaulMutableTreeNodes not contain a loop?

If so, how do we represent something like that using a JTree utility. For example, when you are debugging an application say in eclipse, and you can infinitely use the variable tree in debug mode to keep on looking through a looped object. That is the behavior I am looking for.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's a problem that nodes in a Jtree loop on themselves. Apparently you have a problem only with an "expand all" button, which makes sense because an expand all method will go recursively through the nodes until they have no sons.

`Jtree` does not have an expand all button by default, so I'm guessing yours is already customized...? My suggestion would be either remove the button, or customize the code to stop the expansion if findind a node that was already expanded higher in the hierarchy.